# How did 'sluice' evolve to have 2 distinct meanings?

Tags: etymology

What explains this word's opposing meanings? Can they be conciliated? I already understand and so ask NOT about the definition, below which I want to burrow. I heed the Etymological Fallacy.

> [**sluice**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sluice) = {noun}
>   1.  A sliding gate or other `device for` controlling the flow of water, especially one in a lock gate:
>
> = {verb} [with object] Wash or rinse `freely` with a stream or shower of water:

I don't replicate [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sluice&searchmode=none) because it only explains the noun's etymology. My issue is that any `device for` restricting water flow jars with using water `freely` (verb)?

Comment: They're opposing? A sluice gate can be used both for blocking the flow of water or for letting water flow freely. Just like a light switch turns the light both off and on.

Comment: [In linguistics, *sluicing* has yet another meaning.](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/guess.who.pdf)

Comment: I've just had a look at "sluice" in Collins (noun and verb) and it is understandable how the different meanings are connected. But I doubt that Oxford's example "She sluiced her face with water" is typical usage. It is very far from the technique of a gold digger washing out gold in running water.
http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sluice

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Good question. I have fixed the erroneous link.

Comment: A "sluice" is a narrow channel through which water flows.  A "sluice gate" is a mechanism that cuts off the flow of the water through the channel.  What's so confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common notion in all of the definitions of *[sluice](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sluice)* is controlling the flow of water:

> OED
>
> NOUN
>
> 1.0 (also sluice gate) A sliding gate or other device for controlling the flow of water, especially one in a lock gate:
>
> *The water gushed through the sluices.*
>
> *Lake levels are now regulated by sluices.*
>
> 1.1 (also sluiceway) An artificial water channel for carrying off overflow or surplus water.
>
> 1.2 (In gold mining) a channel or trough constructed with grooves into which a current of water is directed in order to separate gold from the ore containing it.
>
> 2.0 An act of rinsing or showering with water:
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.0 Wash or rinse freely with a stream or shower of water:
>
> *She sluiced her face in cold water.*
>
> Crews sluiced down the decks of their ship
>
> 1.1 [NO OBJECT, WITH ADVERBIAL OF DIRECTION] (Of water) pour or flow freely:
>
> *The waves sluiced over them.*

The etymology **starts** with the *exclusion* of water, but the usage extends from there:

> c.1400, earlier *scluse* (mid-14c.), a shortening of Old French *escluse*
>   "*sluice*, *floodgate*" (Modern French *écluse*),
>
> from Late Latin *exclusa* "*barrier to shut out water*" (in aqua exclusa
>   "*water shut out*," i.e. separated from the river),
>
> from fem. singular of Latin *exclusus*, past participle of *excludere* "*to
>   shut out*"

- The *sluice gate* is a tool to *exclude* water from places where it is undesirable.
- The *sluiceway* is also a tool to carry the water away (because water builds up behind obstacles unless it is carried away), simultaneously carrying water to a more desirable location.
- *By extension*, any act of intentionally moving water in an open channel is the verb *sluice*.
- *By further extension*, the water is carried to *sluice* gold ore, separating heavier gold particles from other sediment.
- *By extension*, any act of washing with running water is associated with *sluice*.
- *By extension*, [re]moving any extraneous material is a metaphorical [*sluice*](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/guess.who.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Well, they are both concerned with the movement of water, so they are not too far apart.

The transference probably happened through the use of "sluice gate". This somehow transformed from *a gate that acts as a sluice* into *a gate that stops a sluice*, that is, the free flow of water.

You might be interested in the  English village of [Seaton Sluice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaton_Sluice), named for a sluice project to stop the harbour silting up.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I have to accept @Peter Shor's comment, I do have some sympathy for your perplexity.

I, too, have always considered the noun, and verb ***sluice*** as strange bedfellows. Especially this is so, in the way the verb is often used today, in accordance with OED sense 4.

> To throw or pour water over (a person or thing); to swill with water,
>   esp. in order to clean or wash; to flush or scour with a rush of
>   water. Also, to fill with water.

This latter use of ***sluice*** seems to have an onomatopoeic quality, the word sounding a bit like that of the flushing water. One might be forgiven for thinking that this was its origin. In fact the etymology of ***sluice*** is from the French ***escluse***, Latin *exclusa*, past participle of *excludere* - to shut out.

Other aspects of the verb, meaning *to let out (water)* do seem to have the appearance of being more obviously related to the noun.

Comment: I've always imagined something like sluicing the deck to be from the image of someone briefly opening a sluice, allowed a pent-up mass of water to suddenly gush forth and spill out over the deck. Obviously, that needs a bit of extension before it works with sluicing your face in the morning (else pray your face doesn't get washed away entirely), but not that much.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But let's say the word  *sluice* from 'closure', had never been invented, and the word 'barrier gate' used instead. Could you imagine *barrier gating* the decks? The word *sluice* immediately suggests something liquid to me.